# How can I create a vertical stepper in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

[Vertical Stepper with text on both sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7mvB.png)

I have looked at all of the components that are available on internet, but I have not been able to find anyone which can be helpful. Anyone who has been able to create a vertical stepper like the one in image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This UI pattern also knows as Timeline:

Try one of these or get inspired by from:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-timeline-flatlist

https://github.com/Syntax00/react-native-just-timeline

Comment: Thank you very much. That resolves my issue. I hadn't been able to find this component by searching.

Comment: Glad it helps. You can approve  answer also